# How to read specific excel table into R

Tags: r

I have 2 tables, `Table_1` and `Table_2`, on one sheet (`sheet_5`) in my excel workbook `myWorkbook.xlsx`. I know there are plenty of packages that allow you to specify which sheet to load in, but is there a way to load in only the table(s) you want? In this case, I want to load `Table_2` only.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most recent version of `readxl` has the ability to set the range. IMHO this is BY FAR the best excel read in package for R.

See the part of this post entitled "Specifying the data rectangle": https://blog.rstudio.org/2017/04/19/readxl-1-0-0/

the syntax should be very familiar to an excel user.

Also please see this post for asking questions on SO: 
[How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I went through the blog post, but I was not able to find any references to load Excel-Tables in a worksheet. By Excel-Table, I am referring to the "structures" we get by clicking Insert > Table; or what are called List Objects in the Excel-VBA World. Is there a way to refer to tables in readxl?

Comment: Hmm... seems like you are wanting to work exclusively in Excel. This is a question about R.

Comment: I have an Excel workbook which hosts all the dimensions tables of my data model. There are multiple tables in a single sheet. I was looking for an easy way to import all excel tables in a workbook into R.

Comment: So your options here are to use a better data structure (i.e. one table per sheet) or use the `range` argument in `readxl::read_excel`.

Comment: I see. Thank you!